# Computing $ \frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2(E(\mathbb{Q}))} $ and its generators (Descent via isogeny method in Silverman)

Tags: elliptic-curves, exact-sequence

I am stuck in the last step of computing the Weak Mordell-Weil group $E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})$ and $E'(\mathbb{Q})/2E'(\mathbb{Q})$ from the two exact sequences
$$
0 \longrightarrow \frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]}{\phi(E(\mathbb{Q})[2])} \longrightarrow \frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{\phi(E(\mathbb{Q}))} 
{\overset{\hat{\phi}}\longrightarrow} 
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2E(\mathbb{Q})} \longrightarrow \frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q}))} \longrightarrow 0.
$$
and 
$$
0 \longrightarrow \frac{E(\mathbb{Q})[\phi]}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q})[2])} \longrightarrow \frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q}))} 
{\overset{\phi}\longrightarrow} 
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{2E'(\mathbb{Q})} \longrightarrow \frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{\phi(E(\mathbb{Q}))} \longrightarrow 0
$$
when I already have the structures of $$\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{\phi(E(\mathbb{Q}))} \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$$ and 
$$\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q}))}  \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$

I think it is not a really difficult thing to do but I still need some confirmation of whether my (half of the)reasoning is correct or not.

In the first exact sequence, the exactness at $\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2(E(\mathbb{Q}))}$ combined with the last map's surjective-ness imply that $$ E(\mathbb{Q}/2E(\mathbb{Q}) / (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $$
Now what should I do?

Also how do I go on to find generators of $\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2(E(\mathbb{Q}))}$, say in the case when $E: y^2 = x^3-5x^2+5x$ isogenous to $E': Y^2 = X^3 +10X^2 + 5X$ via the 2-isogeny
$$ \phi: E \longrightarrow E', \hspace{1.0cm} (x,y) \mapsto \Big(\frac{y^2}{x^2}, \frac{y(5-x^2)}{x^2}\Big)$$ and $$\widehat{\phi}: E' \longrightarrow E \hspace{1.0cm} (X,Y) \mapsto \Big(\frac{Y^2}{4X^2}, \frac{Y(5-X^2)}{8X^2} \Big)$$ and when $\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q}))}$ is generated by $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{{\phi}(E(\mathbb{Q}))}$ is generated by $\{(0,0), (-5,10)\}$.

I would really appreciate any kind of helpful comments and answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will work parallely to the computations in Example 4.10, page 338 (or 303), chapter X [Computing the Mordell-Weil group], section X.4 [The Sel and Sha Groups] from Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.
It uses Proposition X.4.9, page 337 (or 302) in *loc. cit.*, which gives the following **over the rationals**.

---

Let us recall the notations, and the setting of the Proposition X.4.9.

We start with an elliptic curve $E$ over $\Bbb Q$, having a $2$-torsion $\Bbb Q$-rational point, so after passing to an isomorphic elliptic curve, $E$ has the two-torsion point $(0,0)$ and the affine equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\ &:\ y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx\ . 
\\
&\qquad \text{In our example: }a=-5\ ,\ b=5\ :
\\
E\ &:\ y^2=x^3-5x^2+5x\ . 
\end{aligned}
$$
Consider the two-isogenous curve
$$
\begin{aligned}
E'\ &:\ Y^2=X^3+AX^2+BX\ , \qquad A=-2a\ ,\ B=a^2-4b\ .
\\
&\qquad \text{In our example: }A=10\ ,\ B=5\ :
\\
E'\ &:\ Y^2=X^3+10X^2+5X\ . 
\end{aligned}
$$
The isogeny $f:E\to E'$ is given by mapping the point $(x,y)=[x:y:1]$ of $E$ to
the point 
$$
\left(\ \frac{y^2}{x^2}, \ \frac{y(b-x^2)}{x^2}\ \right)
\ =\ \left[
y\ :\ (b-x^2)\ :\ \frac{x^2}y\ \right]
$$
of $E'$, so $T=(0,0)=[0:0:1]$ goes to $[0:b:0]=\infty'=O'$. ($f$ kills the two torsion group generated by $T$.)

The discriminant of $E$ is $4$ times $(e_1-e_2)^2(e_1-e_3)^2(e_2-e_3)^2$, $e_1,e_2,e_3$ being the roots of $x^3+ax^2+b$, so with $e_3=0$ we get $\Delta  =4(e_1e_2)^2(e_1-e_2)^2=4b^2(a^2-4b)=2^2\cdot 5^3$.
Computer check:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( QQ, [0, -5, 0, 5, 0] )
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 5*x^2 + 5*x over Rational Field
sage: E.discriminant().factor()
2^4 * 5^3
```

Moreover:

```
sage: T = E.point( (0,0) )
sage: EE = EllipticCurve( QQ, [0, 10, 0, 5, 0] )
sage: EE
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 10*x^2 + 5*x over Rational Field
sage: f = E.isogeny( kernel=[T], codomain=EE )
sage: f
Isogeny of degree 2
    from Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 5*x^2 + 5*x over Rational Field
    to Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 10*x^2 + 5*x over Rational Field
sage: f(T)
(0 : 1 : 0)
sage: EE.discriminant().factor()
2^8 * 5^3
```

The "singular" places are thus 
$$
S = \{\infty,2,5\}\ .
$$
We have an exact sequence which asks the elements in the group in the middle
$\Bbb Q(S,2)=\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 5,\pm 10\}$ (taken modulo squares)
(with the multiplication as operation)
whether they are "part of domain or cokernel of $\delta$",
$$
0
\longrightarrow
\frac{E'(\Bbb Q)}{fE(\Bbb Q)}
\overset\delta\longrightarrow
\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 5,\pm 10\}
\overset {wc}\longrightarrow
WC(E/\Bbb Q)
\longrightarrow
0\ .
$$
Here, $\delta$ maps a generic point $P'=(X,Y)$ in the quotient of $E'(\Bbb Q)$ by Im$(f)$ to its first component $X$, taken modulo squares, and we also set the neutral element $O'$ to go to $\delta(O')=1$, and for $T'=(0,0)$, we let its image be $\delta(T')=A=(a^2-4b)$ modulo squares.

The map $wc$ maps $d$ (modulo squares) to the class of the curve $C_d$ in the Weil-Chatelet group, where $C_d$ is the following twist:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_d\ :\ 
dw^2 = d^2-2adz^2+(a^2-4b)z^4\ .\text{ In our case:}
\\
dw^2 = d^2 +10dz^2+5z^4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The $f$-Selmer group of $E$ over $\Bbb Q$, sitting in the middle of the exact sequence
$$
0
\to E'(\Bbb Q)/fE(\Bbb Q)\to
\operatorname{Sel}^{(f)}(E:\Bbb Q)
\to Ш(E:\Bbb Q)[f]
\to 0
$$
is then isomorphic to 
$$
\{\ 
d\in\Bbb Q(S,2)\ :\
C_d\text{ has $\Bbb Q_v$-rational points at each $v\in S$ }
\}\ .
$$
There is furthermore a map 
$$
\psi:C_d\to E'\ ,\ (z,w)\to\left( \frac d{z^2},\ \frac{dw}{z^3}\right)\ .
$$
It has the property of mapping a rational point $P$ of $C_d$ to a point $\psi(P)\in E'(\Bbb Q)$, which goes via $\delta$ to $d$ modulo squares.

---

We compute now the given example.

- $\boxed{d=5}$: The point $T'=(0,0)\in E'(\Bbb Q)$ is mapped to $a^2-4b=B=5$, so $5$ is in the $f$-Selmer group.
- $\boxed{d=2}$: $C_2$ is the curve $2w^2=4+20z^2+5z^4$. Suppose there is a point $(z,w)$ of this curve in $\Bbb Q_2$. The $2$-order of $2w^2$ is odd, so it can not be negative, because on the RHS we have only coefficients of even $1$-order, and even $z$-powers. So the point is defined over $\Bbb Z_2$. Since $2w^2$ is divisible by two, we have $z=2Z$. This implies $w=2W$, and we get $2W^2=1+20Z^2+20Z^4$, contradiction.
- $\boxed{d=-1}$: $C_{-1}$ is the curve $-w^2=1-10z^2+5z^4$. By inspection, and by chance for $z=1$ we obtain $w=2$, so the rational point $(1,2)$ is on $C_{-1}$. It is mapped by $\psi$ to $(-1, -2)$, which is a point of $E'(\Bbb Q)$.

This implies that $\operatorname{Sel^{(f)}}(E:\Bbb Q)$, seen inside of $\Bbb Q(S,2)=\langle -1,2,5\rangle$ (modulo squares) is isomorphic to $\langle -1,5\rangle$.

This implies that $E'(\Bbb Q)\to \operatorname{Sel^{(f)}}(E:\Bbb Q)$ is surjective, and that $Ш(E:\Bbb Q)[f]=0$.

The same investigation for $E$ replaced by $E'$, and the homogenous spaces
$$
C'_d\ :\ dw^2=d^2-20dz^2+80z^4\ .
$$

- $\boxed{d=5}$: The point $(0,0)$ is mapped to $A^2-4B=10^2-4\cdot 5=80\equiv 5$ modulo squares, so $5$ is in the Selmer group for the dual.
- $\boxed{d<0}$: There are no points locally over $\Bbb R$, since the RHS in the definition of $C'd$ is positive.
- $\boxed{d=2}$: $C_2$ is the curve $2w^2=4-40z^2+80z^4$. The $2$-order of $2w^2$ is odd, so it can not be negative, else it should be the order of the RHS, which comes from $80z^4$, and is even. Thus a potential $\Bbb Q_2$-rational point is defined over $\Bbb Z_2$. We have then $w=2W$, but then the RHS is not divizible by $8$ in $\Bbb Z_2$. So $2$ is not in the Selmer group.

We have obtained for $g=\hat f$ the identification
$\operatorname{Sel}^{(g)}(E:\Bbb Q)\cong\langle 5\rangle$, and 
$Ш(E':\Bbb Q)[g]=0$.

---

So far we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{E'(\Bbb Q)}{fE(\Bbb Q)}
&
\cong \langle 5,-1\rangle\cong(\Bbb Z/2)^2=\Bbb F_2^2
\\
&\cong 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)\oplus \Bbb F_2(-1,-2)
\ ,\ (0,0)\to 5\ ,\ (-1,-2)\to-1\ ,
\\
\frac{E(\Bbb Q)}{gE'(\Bbb Q)}
&
\cong \langle 5\rangle\cong(\Bbb Z/2)=\Bbb F_2
\\
&\cong 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\ ,\ (0,0)\to 5\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have recovered the same information from the OP, but with the additional data on generators, and rational points on the curves, the non-torsion point $(-1,-2)$ being found by chance.

---

The sequence
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})[g]}{f(E(\mathbb{Q})[2])}
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{fE(\mathbb{Q})} 
\overset g\longrightarrow
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2E(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{gE'(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 0
$$
becomes
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
(\Bbb F_2(0,0)\oplus \Bbb F_2(-1,-2))[g]
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)\oplus \Bbb F_2(-1,-2)
\overset g\longrightarrow
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2E(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\longrightarrow 0
$$
We compute $g=\hat f$ on the torsion point $T'=(0,0)$, (well, $g$ was designed to kill the two-torsion coming from $T'$,) and on the point $Q=(-1,-2)$, getting

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( QQ, [0, -5, 0, 5, 0] )
sage: EE = EllipticCurve( QQ, [0, 10, 0, 5, 0] )
sage: TT = EE.point((0,0))
sage: g = EE.isogeny( kernel=[TT], codomain=E )
sage: Q = EE.point((-1,-2))
sage: g(Q)
(1 : 1 : 1)
sage: g(TT)
(0 : 1 : 0)
```

So $T'\to 0$, and $Q\to P=(1,1)$. The above sequence is than
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)\oplus \Bbb F_2(-1,-2)
\overset g\longrightarrow
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2E(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\longrightarrow 0
$$
and we cancel the $\Bbb F_2(0,0)$ part "on the left side", getting
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(-1,-2)
\overset g\longrightarrow
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{2E(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\longrightarrow 0
$$
This gives the middle term $\cong \Bbb F_2^2$, generated by $P=g(Q)=(1,1)$ and $T=(0,0)$. The two-torsion of $E(\Bbb Q)$ is $\Bbb Z/2$, generated by $T$. 
We have so far $
E(\Bbb Q)
\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2
$.
It turns out that ($P$ is not a non trivial odd multiple of a generator, so) 
$$
E(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Z P\oplus \Bbb Z T
\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2\ .
$$

---

In a similar manner we can analyze the "other side".

---

The sequence
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})[f]}{g(E'(\mathbb{Q})[2])}
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E(\mathbb{Q})}{gE'(\mathbb{Q})} 
\overset f\longrightarrow
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{2E'(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{fE(\mathbb{Q})} 
\longrightarrow 0
$$
becomes
$$
0 
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)[f]
\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)
\overset f\longrightarrow
\frac{E'(\mathbb{Q})}{2E'(\mathbb{Q})} 
\overset\cong\longrightarrow 
\Bbb F_2(0,0)\oplus \Bbb F_2(-1,-2)
\longrightarrow 0\ .
$$
The isogeny $f$ kills the torsion point $T=(0,0)$, so $\Bbb F_2(0,0)[f]
=\Bbb F_2(0,0)$ cancel each other giving immediately the isomorphism $\cong$. We have so far $
E'(\Bbb Q)
\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2
$.
It turns out that $Q=(-1,-2)$ is a generator of the $E'(\Bbb Q)/\text{(Torsion)}\cong\Bbb Z$ part,
$$
E'(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Z Q\oplus \Bbb Z T'
\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2\ .
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the structure of $E'(\mathbb{Q})$ from the structure of $E'(\mathbb{Q})/2E'(\mathbb{Q})$ (and similarly the other). Do you mind explaining that?

Comment: Also, could you explain the last line- how does $(-1,-2)$ turn out to be a generator of the free part of $E'(\mathbb{Q})$ (without using the computer)?

Comment: Because of $E'(\Bbb Q)\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_2$, we already know that $Q(-1,-2)$ is mapped by the above isomorphism in some point $(n,k)\in\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_2$, so in case of $n\ne \pm 1$ ($n$ odd) there would exist a rational point $R$ with $Q=nR$. We apply the canoical height, so $\hat h(Q)=n^2\hat h(R)$.So we may compute the set of all rational points having smaller canonical height. $\hat h$ is related to the "naive" Weil height by $|\hat h-h|=O(1)$, the constant depending on the curve. (Search the net for "differences weil height canonical height".)  Find now points with bounded $h$